# NuGet: Copying .DLL file without creating a reference?

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

I am working on my first [open source project](https://github.com/MadsKirkFoged/SharpFluids) and now I want to [create a NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpFluids/) from it so it is easy to use.
In my project i'm using a DLL (CoolProp.dll) which is a third-party dll.

When running the program it needs to have the dll in:

```
..\bin\Release\CoolProp.dll
```

In the Solution Explorer (VS) I have set the CoolProp.dll to:

```
Build Action: None
Copy to Output Directory: Copy always
```

All this works as it should when just running the code.

In the .nuspec file I have added: (for it to copy the dll file)

```
<file src="bin\Release\CoolProp.dll" target="lib\net461" />
```

When installing the Nuget I get the followering error:

```
Failed to add reference to 'CoolProp'
Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.
```

I am guessing it is trying to add a reference to the dll file, which its shouldn't do. It should just copy it and nothing else.

What am I doing wrong? or is there something I have misunderstood?

Comment: try to add  in the nuspec <references>
      <reference file="CoolProp.dll" />
    </references>

Comment: Did you switch to release configuration before package building?

Comment: @sinitran
I have just tried that and it gave same error

Comment: @Miamy Yes I switched to release

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-content-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got it to work!

My mistake was to put the dll in to the "lib\net461" folder.
As I understand it, putting it into that folder tell the system to make a reference to it.

Instead I did this:

```
<file src="..\CoolProp.dll" target="build\" />
<file src="..\SharpFluids.targets" target="build\" />
```

Created a file name "SharpFluids.targets" and put this into it:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <NativeLibs Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)**\*.dll" />
    <None Include="@(NativeLibs)">
      <Link>%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

So now it just copies the dll file into output-folder without trying to create a reference to it.

Comment: Not working.. Can you explain in more details how it operate. Do you a sample code project.